# Element not iterable if in a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to learn javascript, from these tutorials: https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom, but I've got stuck and not been able to find a solution to the issue. Apologies if this is a recurring question, but I was not able to find a solution using google, all the answers were that the script needed to be at the bottom of the page which I have. Basically, this works fine:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>Javascript Learning</title>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>The</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>has</li>
  <li>passed</li>
</ul>
<script>
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li:last-child');

  for (let elem of elements) {
    alert(elem.innerHTML); // "test", "passed"
  }
</script>
```

But putting the javascript in a separate file like I have will all the other lessons so far. Both .html and .js are in the same folder.

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>Javascript Learning</title>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>The</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>has</li>
  <li>passed</li>
</ul>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li:last-child');

for (let elem of elements) {
    alert(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

The browser gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: elements is not iterable
 file:///home/me/javascript/main.js:26
main.js:26:18

I assumed I must have made an error somewhere, so I cut and pasted straight out of the tutorial to make sure I had not made a syntax error, but still it works if inside the html file and not if it's in it's own separate javascript file. How can this be fixed, I'm fairly sure querySelectorAll is exactly what I need for my site, but I want the javascript in a separate file to keep my code consistent.

Comment: In main.js, is that the only js you have in that file, or is there more?

Comment: I can't recreate your error. are you sure this code is giving you the error?

Comment: I've just copied the code from my post back in and it works. I can only assume a typo, and I think I know where it was, being an emacs person, I suspect there was a semi colon mixed in like this "querySelectorAll;(...)" that was the only way I could recreate it that fits, I unfortunately rewrote it correctly so can't give a definite solution, but it does now work, thank you for your input.